0-1 Linear programming and non-optimal multidimensional knapsack
I would like to create a set of constraints forcing a set of knapsacks to be filled. The knapsacks should be filled, so that no further element of a set of elements fits into it. It is not a classical knapsack problem that aims to find the optimal packing to maximise the resource usage of all resources, or the number of elements included. Instead, it only asks to fill each knapsack, so no leftover element has space to be added. Each element of the set can only be added once to a specific knapsack.
Resulting in something like:
$$
\forall k\in K,\forall e\in E: (1-x(k,e))(\mathbf{s}(k)-\mathbf{c}(e))\leq\sum_{d\in E}\mathbf{c}(d)\cdot x(k,d)-\epsilon,\quad\epsilon>0
$$

knapsack $k$ from set of Knapsacks $K$
element $e$ from set of Elements $E$
binary variable $x(k, e)$ is $1$ if $k$ contains $e$
multidimensional vector of space $s$ in knapsack $k$ is $\mathbf{s}(k)$
$\mathbf{c}(e)$ is the capacity $e$ requires - multidimensional vector
left-hand side represents the space $s$ remaining in knapsack $k$ after adding $e$, if $e$ is not yet present in $k$, $(1-x(k,e))$
right-hand side represents the sum of all currently included elements $e$ in $k$

The dimension $n$ of the vectors result in $n$ separate sets of constraints within the 0-1 LP.
The problem is that for each vector, those constraints have to be linked for each associated vector component.
Hence, for three dimensions always three constraints have to be or combined, since only one has to be true.
This is part of a larger mixed integer linear program I try to construct, and I would like to do this solely by constraints.
Additionally, I'd like the 0-1 LP to choose fitting element combinations by itself and not precompute all possible fittings and just select a fitting. (Those conditions are important in the context of the larger MILP)
Does anybody have an idea how to do it? (Tried to use this resource, but didn't manage to construct a solution: https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mipform/dhtml/chap2s1.html?scroll=ssecabsval )

First, just to be clear, a given element can be added to more than one knapsack (at most once per knapsack)? Have you considered using the objective function to maximize the number of items packed? (In the context of the larger problem, this could be added as a reward to the objective function or set as a secondary objective using lexicographic optimization).

@prubin yep, at most once per knapsack. With objective function, I always end up, with competing objectives (from the remaining MILP) and with either maximising towards the best possible fit (e.g. depending on the element vector contributions to different dimensions) or maximising the number of elements in a knapsack - always favouring certain setups over others. I have no experience with lex... opt and how well it handles competing objectives. Does your answer imply that what I intend to do is in most cases worse than your proposals?

Whether what you intend is worse than lexicographic optimization depends on whether forcing the knapsacks to be full to the point that no other item can be taken hurts the original objective of the problem or not, and perhaps on whether the introduction of additional binary variables and constraints (see Rob Pratt's answer) slows down solution of the overall model too much.

You want to enforce the logical implication
$$x(k,e) = 0 \implies \bigvee_{i=1}^n \left(\mathbf{s}_i(k)-\mathbf{c}_i(e) \le \sum_{d\in E}\mathbf{c}_i(d)\cdot x(k,d)-\epsilon\right)$$
Introduce binary decision variable $y(k,e,i)$ and impose indicator constraints
\begin{align}
x(k,e) = 0 &\implies \sum_{i=1}^n y(k,e,i) \ge 1 \\
y(k,e,i) = 1 &\implies \mathbf{s}_i(k)-\mathbf{c}_i(e) \le \sum_{d\in E}\mathbf{c}_i(d)\cdot x(k,d)-\epsilon
\end{align}
If your solver does not support indicator constraints, you can linearize via big-M as follows:
\begin{align}
1 - x(k,e) &\le \sum_{i=1}^n y(k,e,i) \\
y(k,e,i) (\mathbf{s}_i(k)-\mathbf{c}_i(e)+\epsilon) &\le \sum_{d\in E}\mathbf{c}_i(d)\cdot x(k,d)
\end{align}
